# Configure Remote Desktop for Administrator with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

Is it possible to configure Remote Desktop for Administrator using PowerShell without installing the "Remote Desktop Session Host" role on all our servers? We're after the RemoteDesktopServices module.

The docs here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc743159.aspx say

"To allow remote connections for administrative purposes only, you do not have to install an RD Session Host server."

but all the instructions for using PowerShell seem to require the extra role. Is it necessary, and if so, what the implications, as it seems to be a much broader set of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Using wmi you can do it without RDSH (copy&paste from [here](http://4sysops.com/archives/enable-remote-desktop-on-remote-computers-with-powershell/) )

```
$RDP = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TerminalServiceSetting `
            -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices `
            -Computer $Computer `
            -Authentication 6 `
            -ErrorAction Stop

$result = $RDP.SetAllowTsConnections(1,1)
   if($result.ReturnValue -eq 0) {
   Write-Host "$Computer : Enabled RDP Successfully"
   "$Computer : RDP Enabled Successfully" | Out-File -FilePath $SuccessComps -Append
 } else {
   Write-Host "$Computer : Failed to enabled RDP"
   "$Computer : Failed to enable RDP" | Out-File -FilePath $FailedComps -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks C.B. The actual setting we're trying to change is the time limit policy? I can't find anything in the docs for that though - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383640(v=vs.85).aspx - but we can change it through the UI... any ideas?